# local constant $\Rightarrow$ global constant

Tags: complex-analysis

> > Let $f\colon M\to\mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic, localy constant function, $M\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ open and connected. Show, that then $f$ is constant on whole $M$.

Isn't this an easy consequence of the identity theorem, i.e:

$f$ is constant localy, i.e. there exist $x_0\in M, r>0, c\in\mathbb{C}$, so that
$$
f(x)=c~\forall~x\in B(r,x_0).
$$

So $x_0$ is a limit point of
$$
\left\{z\in M: f(z)=c\right\}
$$
and the identity theorem says that
$$
f=c~\forall~z\in M.
$$

That's it already?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: You don't even need holomorphicity. A locally constant function on a connected set is constant.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: I guess that in OP's words a "locally constant" function is one that is constant in a neighborhood of (at least) a single point.

Comment: Open and connected implies path connectedness. Any two points can be joined by some path $\gamma$. Hence $f \circ \gamma:[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ has derivative zero and so is constant.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so this question has an answer, yes, that's it.

If by locally constant you mean each point has a neighbourhood on which the function is constant, then you don't even need the function to be holomorphic. If, however, you mean there is a point with a neighbourhood on which the function is constant, then you do need holomorphicity, in particular the Identity Theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.