# Does $|f|$ locally constant imply $f$ constant globally?

Tags: complex-analysis

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480801/local-constant-rightarrow-global-constant) the following statement was shown:

> Let $f\colon M\to\mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic, $M\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ open and connected, $z_0 \in M$ and $f$ is constant in an neighborhood of $z_0$. Then $f$ is constant on the whole $M$.

I wonder if it holds that

> If $f\colon M\to\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, $M\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ open and connected, $z_0 \in M$ and $|f|$ is constant in an neighborhood of $z_0$. Then $f$ is constant on the whole $M$.

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we have $|f|=c$ on some $D(z_0,r) \subset M,$ then $f(D(z_0,r))$ is contained in the circle $\{|w|=c\}.$ Thus $f(D(z_0,r))$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb C.$ Hence on $D(z_0,r),$ $f$ is constant by the open mapping theorem. So by the result you first cited, $f$ is constant in $M.$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if $f$ is holomorphic and $|f|$ is constant on some open set $U$, then $f$ is constant. This follows from writing $f(z)= |f(z)| e^{i F(z)}$ where $F(z) : U \to \mathbb R$.

In this situation note that if $|f(z)|=0$, then $f$ is constant. If it is not zero then, since $\ln$ is analytic, $i\, F(z)$ must be holomorphic on $U$.

But since $F$ maps onto the reals, the Cauchy Riemann equations give you:

$$\partial_x F = \partial_x \Re(F) = \partial_y \Im(F) = 0\\
\partial_y F = \partial_y \Re(F) = -\partial_x \Im(F) = 0$$

This can only be satisfied if $F$ is also constant.

Comment: As far as I can tell it shows that $f$ is constant on $U$. But what about $f$ globally?

Comment: @Leo you can use the identity theorem to see that, or consider that the conditions of your first statement have been shown to hold.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thanks.

Comment: I think $U$ must be connected.

Comment: @C.Dubussy you are right about that, the argument shows that $f$ is locally constant (on $U$). For connected sets this is equivalent to constant.